# EXCEL Any way to copy every iteration result into a separate table?

Tags: excel, save, iteration, output

I have a following problem:
I want to try different  values for say cell A1. Every time I input the value into A1, cells B1, C1, D1 and E1 change. Is there any way to make a new table that would automatically copy results of the of these iterations into separate cells. So for example:
I choose A1 = 10. This automatically appears at A3. All the values of B1, C1, D1 and E1 are then automaticall stored at B3, C3, D3 and E3. I then change A1 = 20. All new values of B1, C1, D1 and E1 are now stored at B4, C4, D4 and E4.

Any suggestions on how to do that ? 
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in the sheets Worksheet_Change module, and the results will be added from row 3 and downward every time a change to cell A1 is made.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3

    'If there is a change to A1
    If Target.Address = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Address Then
        Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I shortened your code a bit, hope you don't mind. Also, instead of looping through the cells until you find vbNullString, simply use the `.End` property, as Roro shows in his answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. if A1 change, cell b1, c1, d1, and e1 change, this can resolve by ussually code
2. for automatic add new row you can use this macro

> ```
> Sub Macro4()
> '
> ' Macro4 Macro
> '
> ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
> '
> Range("A1:E1").Select
> Selection.Copy
> Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
> ActiveSheet.Paste
> End Sub
> ```

to use that macro you just press ctrl + t, (keyboard shortcut is up to you)